# botpress - increment vlaue

Tags: javascript, increment, botpress

I am trying to get a custom action running to simply incrementing a value on passing a specific node on the flow.

My custom actions looks like this:

```js
function action(bp: typeof sdk, event: sdk.IO.IncomingEvent, args: any, { user, temp, session } = event.state) {
  /** Your code starts below */

  let i = undefined

  const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (i === undefined) {
      resolve((i = 0))
    } else if (i >= 0) {
      resolve(i + 1)
    } else {
      reject('i cannot be < 0')
    }
  })

  const runCount = async () => {
    try {
      const counter = await p
      i = counter
      return (session.count = counter)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }

  return runCount()

  /** Your code ends here */
}
```

When I runCount() variable i will be set to 0. But then, after in rerun runCount() it does not increment further.

What do I need to do to save the variable so it increments on every runCount() call.

Greetings
Lorenz

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to solve the problem.

I had to declare i = session.count at the beginning.

Now it gets the value out of the session state and increments the state on every call.

Maybe someone gets some help out of this.

Lorenz